# how to solve the error: 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, oop, attributeerror

```
class Song:
    """
    Creates an object of song with attributes as:

    name: name of the song
    artist: name of the artist who created the song
    duration: duration of the song
    """
    def __init__(self, name, artist):
        self.name = name
        self.artist = artist
#       self.duration = duration


class Album:
    """
    creates an album object with attributes as:
    name: name of the album
    year: year of release
    artist: name of the artist

    Method
    add_song: contains the list of the songs in the album object
    """

    def __init__(self, name, year, artist=None):
        self.name = name
        self.year = year
        self.tracks = []
        if artist is None:
            self.artist = Artist('various artist')
        else:
            self.artist = artist

    def add_song(self, name, position=None):
        """ add a song to the tracks list"""

        new_song = find_object(name, self.tracks)
        if new_song is None:
            new_song = Song(name, self.artist)
        else:
            if position is None:
                self.tracks.append(new_song)
            else:
                self.tracks.insert(position, new_song)


class Artist:
    """
    creates an artist object having the attributes:

    name: name of the artist

    method:
    add_album: adds album to the album list, if the album already exists it does not add

    add_song: adds song to the album
    """
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.albums = []

    def add_album(self, album):
        """
        a method to add album to the albums list for the artist
        :param album: the name of the album to be added
        """
        self.albums.append(album)

    def add_song(self, name, year, title):
        """
        adds a song to an album and creates an album if album doesn't exist
        :param name: name of the album
        :param year: year of release
        :param title: name of the song
        """
        album_found = find_object(name, self.albums)
        if album_found is None:
            album_found = Album(name, year, self)
            print(name, ' not found')
            self.add_album(album_found)
        else:
            print(name, ' found')

        album_found.add_song(title)


def find_object(field, object_list):
    for item in object_list:
        if item.name == field:
            item = field
            return item
        return None


def load_data():
    artist_list = []

    with open(r"E:\kgp\python\albums.txt", "r") as check_list:
        for i in check_list.readlines():
            artist_field, album_field, year_field, song_field = tuple(i.strip('\n').split('\t'))
            year_field = int(year_field)
            new_artist = find_object(artist_field, artist_list)
            if new_artist is None:
                new_artist = Artist(artist_field)
                artist_list.append(new_artist)

            new_artist.add_song(album_field, year_field, song_field)

    return artist_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    artist = load_data()
    print(artist)
```

Whenever I'm running this code I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\ritvi\IdeaProjects\Object_Orienteted_programing\songs_docstring.py", line 114, in 
> artist = load_data()
> File "C:\Users\ritvi\IdeaProjects\Object_Orienteted_programing\songs_docstring.py", line 108, in load_data
> new_artist.add_song(album_field, year_field, song_field)
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_song'

Answer (score 0):

from the flow of your program :

you do:
`for i in open(r"E:\kgp\python\albums.txt", "r")` where i is text

then:
`artist_field = i.strip('\n').split('\t')[0]`where artist_field is text

then:
`new_artist = find_object(artist_field, artist_list)` where new_artist is text

then:
`new_artist.add_song(album_field, year_field, song_field)` where new_artist is text and so it don't have the `add_song` function